# What does "Semantic Constraints" mean regarding Software Testing?

Tags: testing, semantics, software-design

There are several methods in Software Testing to decide which test cases to use. One method for Test Case Selection is Combinatorial Testing. In order to reduce the amount of test cases used in Combinatorial Testing one can use one of the following Rules:

-Semantic Constraints

-Combinatorial Constraints

-Random Constraints

What are Semantic Constraints and how do they differ from the other constraints?

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't heard about semantic constraints before, so I had to Google it up. I found some explanation from [Software Testing and Analysis: Process, Principles, and Techniques](http://ix.cs.uoregon.edu/~michal/book/) by Mauro Pezzè and Michal Young, chapter 13, functional testing. Apparently it means that if there is a lot of combinations of variables, you can apply semantical constraints, that is not test combinations that do not make sense (like invalid combinations in the context). Who would have thought?

Answer (score 0):

The use of semantic constraint depends heavily on the user’s knowledge about the condition where a product is used and how it relates to the physical world. Indeed, different products are being used in different conditions to carry out their functions. Users have to depend on their tacit knowledge to determine the actions needed to be performed under a certain condition to get functions from a product. Based on this approach the test cases will be decided. For example, the function of a car is to transport people from a point to another. The car must be running on the road and the driver must be seated facing the front in order to see the road. The actions of driving the car on the road and sitting facing the front to operate a car would be considered as a semantic constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently watching "Software Architecture in Practice Live Lessons" on safaribooksonline.

The term came up when describing Architectural Patterns in Lesson 4.1

It's described generally as what a pattern allows you to do and not do.